# Recovering Windows and/or system restore after faulty driver install

Tags: windows-7, drivers, windows-registry, bsod, system-restore

I installed HP's sound driver yesterday and it BSOD-ed my windows and crashed it. System repair didn't help. System restore is corrupted, and startup recovery just says `patch is preventing windows from starting`. When I try to boot, it loads up to certain amount of time and then in just BSOD-s to generic error code.

I disabled the new driver in registry, but it didn't help. I then installed another windows copy on a new partition, and tried copying over the registry and `system32\drivers` folder, still the same issue.

Any further ideas? If I could somehow just use the files from system restore that are not corrupted, and leave the rest out, that would help but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: The code you have provided typically can be for not understanding any device. I suggest you unplug everything other than barebones to see if the issue persists. At what point does it BSOD exactly and, does the issue persists when loading into Safe Mode?

Comment: safe mode doesn't work. it crashes at a certain point, so I can't clean boot in any way I know. Is there a way to clean boot by modifying the registry? It seems that bsod happens after all drivers have been loaded.

Comment: it stops at classpnp.sys. but I deleted everything from drivers folder and pasted over the ones from new installation and it didn't change a thing

Comment: IDT High definition audio codec. I disabled the driver in registry

Comment: It's a laptop, no external devices.

Comment: Slightly related: http://superuser.com/questions/174939/patch-is-preventing-the-system-from-starting-need-to-manually-uninstall-windows

Comment: windows 7 home premium 64bit

Comment: Last known good config?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reinstallation was the only way to go unfortunatly. I tried replacing windows files, reintegrating registry.. nothing gave stable results. 
This is not a solution, as I was trying to fix the computer, not reinstall OS.

Comment: reinstalling operating system is not a solution. and in my question it was clear that I already tried to repair. Of course I knew that reinstalling my OS would fix the problem , I'm not an idiot. I wanted to fix the problem without having to resort to that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to perform a repair, or even a re-installation.

You can download the [ISO for Windows 7](http://www.mydigitallife.info/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-from-digital-river/) on another machine, burn it to disk and see if this gives you the options you need to either repair or re-install.

Comment: you will notice that system repair didn't help in my first post. as to reinstall, I know that reinstaling windows would fix it, but the goal was to avoid reinstall. thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Just try to take battery out of board, wait 2 minutes and then put it back and see if it helps.

Comment: It sounds like Netismine you have tried every possible piece of troubleshooting I can think of. Personally, I would rip out the hard drive, chuck it in another computer, back up anything important and do a reformat. Not to mention it will also get rid of all the bloatware HP puts on their machines. Try to think of it as starting fresh for 2013 ;)

Comment: That's what I did in the end. It was troublesome cause I had my woking environment set up. Ironic thing is that faulty driver was supplied by HP support staff.

Answer (score 0):

Messing up everything, then trying too fix it after nothing would work correctly on restarting your PC. Messing with registry, you are trying to paste it back together. Come-on, you needed to try SlimDrivers Program. I say you needed to enter info on the website of laptop,serial # such to find your laptop listed there. Get proper installs, re-installing windows (R) i did to fix my problems but burning up alot of free space on my drive. CCleaner is the program for cleaning up the registry.